# Why the exported GLTF model looks bigger and in a different position than in Blender?

Tags: bones, gltf

I have this model:

[image]

But the final export looks bigger and in a different position:

[image]

Comment: First thing that comes to mind: have you applied scale and rotation on the model with Ctrl+A before exporting?

Comment: How do you know it looks bigger? Do you know the size of the grids in each software?

Answer (score 2):

this photo shows default settings, if you havent change any, this is what yours looks like.

what might help is if you change these two settings to the following:

**set FALSE the y+ up option in the export settings**

**set TRUE for apply modifiers**

most likely removing the armature is changing the size, if you set apply modifiers to true this wont happen anymore as the modifier is applied and not removed

y+ up is changing the orientation on export

[image]